# Chat client spam filter rework and advice

Tags: c#, datetime, timer

I have read a couple different threads on how Chat Clients should handle spam but I still don't know which path for handling this issue would have the best result.

I've seen from this thread: [Chat spam auto block for C# chat client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11606455/chat-spam-auto-block-for-c-sharp-chat-client) that if you use Time Stamps from DateTime and compare them with intervals you can make a pretty darn good spam filter. I however am not an expert programmer by any means and am having a hard time grasping the concept of comparing previous DateTime stamps with Timer intervals; or I might be missing the point.

So with this in mind I have dabbled with some C# code and want you to recommend a better way of constructing this idea with either just Timers, DateTime stamps, or both...

```
    private void Post()
    {
        string time = DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm:ss");
        string data = UserInput.Text;
        _GetData(time + " " + lUser + PROMPT + data);
        ChatWindow.SetSelected(ChatWindow.Items.Count - 1, true);
        ChatWindow.SetSelected(ChatWindow.Items.Count - 1, false);
        UserInput.Clear();
    }

    System.Timers.Timer resetTimer = new System.Timers.Timer();
    private int MessageCount { get; set; }
    private bool isSpam { get; set; }

    private void SpamEvent(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (MessageCount <= 2)
        {
            MessageCount -= 1;
            isSpam = false;
        }
        else
        {
            isSpam = true;
        }
    }

    private void ResetTimer(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        MessageCount = 0;
        btnEnter.Enabled = true;
    }

    private void btnEnter_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MessageCount += 1;
        System.Timers.Timer localtimer = new System.Timers.Timer();
        localtimer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(SpamEvent);
        localtimer.Interval = 1000;
        localtimer.Enabled = true;

        if (isSpam == false)
        {
            Post();
        }
        if (isSpam == true)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("No spamming please");
            btnEnter.Enabled = false;
            resetTimer.Interval = 5000;
            resetTimer.SynchronizingObject = this;
            resetTimer.Enabled = true;
            resetTimer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(ResetTimer);
        }
    }
```

Or something like:

```
        List<DateTime> myMessage = new List<DateTime>();

        DateTime local = new DateTime();
        local = DateTime.Now;
        myMessage.Add(local);

        int Messages = myMessage.Count;
        System.Timers.Timer localtimer = new System.Timers.Timer();
```

I am currently in school taking another full load of classes. This between work, girlfriend, class, and family duties it is making my head spin.

Comment: The local timer only servers as a watchdog timer for the execution time of the Post() method. So, if Post()'s execution time is longer than 1 sec., Spam will be flagged. That's not what you intended, right?

Comment: Right, I will add some code later on for decrements on the message count if when the Spam method is false. Or do you think something else should be used entirely?

Comment: See my answer about the general control flow your code should implement...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Make localTimer a private member of the class and rename it to "spamTimer" or something (nomen est omen).
2. In your btn_click method, check first if the resetTimer is started and still running (not yet elapsed). If so, it means we are in the spam penalty delay. Show MessageBox, but do no further processing.
3. After checking resetTimer, check if the spamTimer has been started. If it is not started yet, start it. However, if spamTimer is already running (not yet elapsed) and the message count is >2, do not execute Post because spam is detected. Set the isSpam flag accordingly and start the reset timer. Show MessageBox, but do no further processing...
4. After checking spamTimer, post the message. And increment the message counter of course...
5. When resetTimer elapses, reset the isSpam flag and messageCount.

Comment: Thank you, I will diagram this when I have more time... also the answered thread in <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11606455/chat-spam-auto-block-for-c-sharp-chat-client> recommends that I should not be regulating total spam at the client level because of reasoning that the source code can be modified. Do you recommend that I just send the DateTime stamps to my chat server and then compute the spam that way? Or should I just compute the spam on the local client and then send the result to the server?

Comment: Do everything on the server.  Always assume your clients are trying to hack you.  All the user would send is the message, you would then associate that message with a user (based on session or something) and compute the timestamp the message was received by you.

Comment: You will have to do spam checks on the server too. As Micah said, you cannot trust ANY information coming from the client. Heck, somebody could just write his own fake client software just to fool your server.

Answer (score 0):

The following will make it so a user's message will be discarded if they send more than 10 per minute.  This allows the user to send multiple messages in a row as long as overall they aren't sending too much.  Conceptually, "ChatMessageReceived" would be called anytime a message from a user arrives on the chat server.

```
class Message
{
    public readonly String Author;
    public readonly String Content;
    public readonly DateTimeOffset Time = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow;
    public Message(String author, String content)
    {
        Author = author;
        Content = content;
    }
}

class Chat
{
    // collection of recent messages
    private IList<Message> _recentMessages = new List<Message>();

    public void ChatMessageReceived(String author, String content)
    {
        // prune the recentMessages down to only messages in the last minute
        var oneMinuteAgo = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow - TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1);
        _recentMessages = (from message in _recentMessages where message.Time > oneMinuteAgo select message).ToList();

        // get the number of recent messages sent by this author
        var countOfRecentMessagesFromAuthor = _recentMessages.Count(message => message.Author == author);
        if (countOfRecentMessagesFromAuthor > 10)
            return;

        // add the new message to the collection of recent messages.
        _recentMessages.Add(new Message(author, content));

        // Record the chat message and display it or send it to connected clients.
    }
}
```

Comment: Since I really don't have any books at the moment about C# programming and am really just learning this at my own pace. How can I relate this code you've provided to my code? Don't get me wrong I think you have created something great, it's just I'm not there yet D: